Can I have more streams than just stdout, stdin and stderr?
I have a process which will run a subprocess. Both will talk to a device through a serial port. The subprocess will be executing the custom code of a programmer using my library. Sometimes the programmer might want to wait on a response, and sometimes the device can send data on its own to both the process and the subprocess (broadcast). All of this goes to the stdin buffer which I'd have to filter for the wanted data. I'd like to have another stream, maybe couple, for easy data acquisition.

Yes, of course, you can.

@UlrichEckhardt but how?

IMO a more detailed description of the problem may help get the answer you are looking for.
